# BoneCP datasource opens many threads to manage the connections in application

Tags: bonecp

BoneCP datasource opens many threads to manage the connections. Is there a way where it opens only single thread for all the datasources opened?

```
      Daemon Thread [com.google.common.base.internal.Finalizer] (Running)   
      Daemon Thread [BoneCP-keep-alive-scheduler] (Running) 
      Daemon Thread [BoneCP-pool-watch-thread] (Running)
```